# EditText in ExpandableListView parent layout not focusable and expandable together

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, expandablelistview, focusable

I have a group layout with an EditText and a RadioButton.

[image]

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:focusable="false"/>
```

My List has the attribute `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"`

The problem is, I can either let the EditText have focus or the list item itself which inflates the group, but not both together.

I´ve tried to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to the manifest without having any effect.

My Child Views are all fine, all EditText´s are working and so on.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same question and problem.

Comment: Nope, sorry. I redesigned my layout and don´t need it anymore. Anyway, I would be happy to see a solution

Comment: @MarianKlühspies Hey you got solution?

Comment: @DivyangPatel Hello, nope. I´ve removed the EditText and replaced it with a TextView and a CheckBox. It turned out that it was totally uneccessary in my case.

Comment: @MarianKlühspies I am facing same issue.i want to add edittext with expandableview.is it possible to add edittext with expandable view?

Comment: @MarianKlühspies [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612903/expandablelistview-is-not-getting-expanded-when-edittext-is-added-in-parent-xml) check this issue.